# AWS S3 Public (with restricted regional access) bucket access with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a public bucket in S3 with a policy that only allows regional access from us-west-1 and us-west-2. I want to access this bucket anonymously in Python using boto3/s3fs and list all files in it, but wonder how you can do it without signing in using credentials.

```
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "us-west-1",
                        "us-west-2"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I tried something like this:

```py
s3_client =  boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2', config=Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED))
s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='MY-BUCKET')
```

but it did not work, returning an access denied error.

Note that it does work if I did not specify the requestedregion, so I wonder if there's something I can do to configure the function/bucket policy for it to work.

Comment: If you specify the region URL when building the client, do you still get the error?
```
s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    endpoint_url='https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    config=Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED)
)```

Comment: And do you have access to the AWS CLI? if you do, if you run this do you get a more descriptive error message?

aws s3 ls s3://MY-BUCKET/ --region us-west-2 --no-sign-request

Comment: @Jess apparently the endpoint_url 's3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' does not exist. And of course there's access denied error when I tried to list the bucket content using AWS CLI, due to the regional restriction